# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' (KNN model)

Tags: python, attributeerror, knn, train-test-split

I am trying to use KNN Regression model in my code but it is showing an Attribute error. Logistic Regression and Decision Tree Classifier have worked just fine.

**Here is the code**

```
    sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    KNN = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(X_train,Y_train)
    train_preds5 = KNN.predict(X_train)
    print("Model accuracy on train is: ", accuracy_score(Y_train, train_preds5))
```

**Here is the error**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[87], line 5
      3 KNN = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(X_train,Y_train)
      4 #predict on train 
----> 5 train_preds5 = KNN.predict(X_train)
      6 #accuracy on train
      7 print("Model accuracy on train is: ", accuracy_score(Y_train, train_preds5))

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py:234, in KNeighborsClassifier.predict(self, X)
    218 """Predict the class labels for the provided data.
    219 
    220 Parameters
   (...)
    229     Class labels for each data sample.
    230 """
    231 if self.weights == "uniform":
    232     # In that case, we do not need the distances to perform
    233     # the weighting so we do not compute them.
--> 234     neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False)
    235     neigh_dist = None
    236 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py:824, in KNeighborsMixin.kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    817 use_pairwise_distances_reductions = (
    818     self._fit_method == "brute"
    819     and ArgKmin.is_usable_for(
    820         X if X is not None else self._fit_X, self._fit_X, self.effective_metric_
    821     )
    822 )
    823 if use_pairwise_distances_reductions:
--> 824     results = ArgKmin.compute(
    825         X=X,
    826         Y=self._fit_X,
    827         k=n_neighbors,
    828         metric=self.effective_metric_,
    829         metric_kwargs=self.effective_metric_params_,
    830         strategy="auto",
    831         return_distance=return_distance,
    832     )
    834 elif (
    835     self._fit_method == "brute" and self.metric == "precomputed" and issparse(X)
    836 ):
    837     results = _kneighbors_from_graph(
    838         X, n_neighbors=n_neighbors, return_distance=return_distance
    839     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_dispatcher.py:277, in ArgKmin.compute(cls, X, Y, k, metric, chunk_size, metric_kwargs, strategy, return_distance)
    196 """Compute the argkmin reduction.
    197 
    198 Parameters
   (...)
    274 returns.
    275 """
    276 if X.dtype == Y.dtype == np.float64:
--> 277     return ArgKmin64.compute(
    278         X=X,
    279         Y=Y,
    280         k=k,
    281         metric=metric,
    282         chunk_size=chunk_size,
    283         metric_kwargs=metric_kwargs,
    284         strategy=strategy,
    285         return_distance=return_distance,
    286     )
    288 if X.dtype == Y.dtype == np.float32:
    289     return ArgKmin32.compute(
    290         X=X,
    291         Y=Y,
   (...)
    297         return_distance=return_distance,
    298     )

File sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_argkmin.pyx:95, in sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin.ArgKmin64.compute()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py:139, in threadpool_limits(limits, user_api)
    137     return controller.limit(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
    138 else:
--> 139     return threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:171, in threadpool_limits.__init__(self, limits, user_api)
    167 def __init__(self, limits=None, user_api=None):
    168     self._limits, self._user_api, self._prefixes = \
    169         self._check_params(limits, user_api)
--> 171     self._original_info = self._set_threadpool_limits()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:268, in threadpool_limits._set_threadpool_limits(self)
    265 if self._limits is None:
    266     return None
--> 268 modules = _ThreadpoolInfo(prefixes=self._prefixes,
    269                           user_api=self._user_api)
    270 for module in modules:
    271     # self._limits is a dict {key: num_threads} where key is either
    272     # a prefix or a user_api. If a module matches both, the limit
    273     # corresponding to the prefix is chosed.
    274     if module.prefix in self._limits:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:340, in _ThreadpoolInfo.__init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    337     self.user_api = [] if user_api is None else user_api
    339     self.modules = []
--> 340     self._load_modules()
    341     self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342 else:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:373, in _ThreadpoolInfo._load_modules(self)
    371     self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372 elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373     self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374 else:
    375     self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:485, in _ThreadpoolInfo._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    482         filepath = buf.value
    484         # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485         self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486 finally:
    487     kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:515, in _ThreadpoolInfo._make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513 if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514     module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515     module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516     self.modules.append(module)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:606, in _Module.__init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604 self.internal_api = internal_api
    605 self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606 self.version = self.get_version()
    607 self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608 self._get_extra_info()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:646, in _OpenBLASModule.get_version(self)
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
    647 if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648     return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I tried to import KNN Regression model and use it perform a prediction and check the accuracy on the Dataset I am using.
I was expecting it to show an accuracy score but it showed an Attribute Error instead.

Comment: What does your X_train, Y_train look like- the shape and dtypes?

Comment: **Code** :`X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=40)
print (X.shape,Y.shape)
print(X_train.shape,X_test.shape,Y_train.shape,Y_test.shape)`. **Output** : (195, 22) (195,)
(156, 22) (39, 22) (156,) (39,)